# Carving a rectilinear polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

In this question, **carving** a polygon $P$ means removing an axis-parallel rectangle adjacent to the boundary of $P$. Carving $P$ might break it into two or more polygons.

You are given a square $P$. You have to carve in $n$ times, such that the resulting polygon (or polygons) $P'$ has a large *rectangle-number*. The rectangle-number is defined as the smallest number of pairwise-disjoint rectangles in a partition of $P'$.

For example, in the figure below:

[image]

the square is carved 3 times. The rectangle-numbers are written in each resulting polygon. The final rectangle-number is 6, since $P'$, which is a union of two polygons, can be partitioned to 6 pairwise-disjoint rectangles.

Let $R(n)$ be the largest rectangle-number that you can achieve in $n$ carvings. The example above shows that $R(3)\geq 6$.

**What is an upper bound on $R(n)$?**

In the example above, each carving adds at most 2 to the rectangle-number. This hints that there may be an upper bound such as $R(n)\leq (2n+1)$, or maybe another linear upper-bound.

EDIT: while there are scenarios in which a single carving can double the rectangle-number:

[image]

they still do not contradict the conjecture that $R(n)\leq (2n+1)$, since many carvings are needed in order to reach such a scenario (in that example: 16 carvings). Is there a way to formalize this argument?